# Mixing Annotated Beans and Declarative AOP transcation

Tags: spring, transactions, annotations

I have an existing project using Declarative AOP transcation, i want to add Annotated Beans using @Service, @Repository, @Component, but transaction is not working for Annotated Services, but declarative beans have no issue, my question is that is it possible to mix Annotated Beans and Declarative AOP transcation in one project, if so, how to implement it? Is there any difference between declarative beans and annotated beans? Bare me if the question is too stupid, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, servlet-context level again scan the DAO, Manager, Service layer, but transaction is define in application-context level, the solution is make servlet-context level only scan Controller.